# Hyperlink that can lead to a pdf in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm working with Jupyter notebook and have a question in mind:

If I want to markdown an HTML file or any website, I can just simply do

```
[name-of-the-website](address-here)
```

and it will create a link to the page that I want to reference

**My question is**

---

1. Are there any markdown code for PDF reference
2. IS the code the same with HTML reference (whenver I click into the markdown link, It will create a new tab which can download the file to the computer)

P/s: I'm not talking about coverting the notebook into PDF file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out an answer:

Go to the file PDF that you want to download, for example I want to download [this PDF file](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/services/stochastic/pubs/2009/DMWG09/dumont-visapp09-shortpaper.pdf)

---

**Ideas**:

Because there should be a HTML link to download the document, if one can find this link, then can proceed to normal markdown HTML file in Jupyter Notebook

---

**Steps**:

1. On the browser, right-click that PDF download link, and then choose `Inspect Element (Q)` (on Firefox or any browser in use)
2. It is then open the console that will shown the download HTML file like shown:
   `href="http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/services/stochastic/pubs/2009/DMWG09/dumont-visapp09-shortpaper.pdf"`
3. One can proceed with normal markdown in Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<a href = "test.pdf"> ref. </a>
```

This is a relative path to the file.